# Should I expect it to be a chicken or a penguin?

Tags: probability, bayesian, classification

An alien is trying to classify a group of only chickens and penguins into, well, chickens and penguins by analyzing 3 independent boolean features A, B, C.

If the animal (in reality) is a chicken, A holds for the animal 60% of the time, B holds 10% of the time, C holds 80% of the time.

If the animal is actually a penguin,  A holds for it 55% of the time, B holds for it 20% of the time, and C holds for it 90% of the time.

The alien observes an animal (that must be either a chicken or a penguin) for which A and B hold, but C is false. Is the animal most likely a chicken?

Is the answer just the greater of $0.6 * 1 + 0.1 * 1 + 0.8 * 0$ and $0.55 * 1 + 0.2 * 1 + 0.9 * 0$? Since the features are all independent?

Comment: One reason I feel that this answer is sketchy is that I am completely doing away with the third variable $C$. It's not even being considered anymore.

Comment: I think I would include $0.2$ & $0.1$ for C, instead of $0.8*0$ & $0.9*0$, to get the joint probability of observing those values given that the bird is a chicken or a penguin. A situation like this could be analyzed w/ logistic regression, but what you have is not actually a LR equation.

Comment: I think there is insufficient information; you need to also know how many chickens and penguins there are.

Answer (score 9):

Expanding on my comment; let's simplify. Suppose there is *one* Boolean variable A. Suppose that, if the animal is a chicken, A is true 60% of the time and, if the animal is a penguin, it is true 10% of the time.

Now given A, what is the probability it is a chicken?

No way to know. We could have

```
1000 chickens - 600 with A = 1 and 400 with A = 0
10 penguins -    10 with A = 1 and 90 with A = 0
```

given A = 1, the probability that it's a chicken is 600/610

or we could have

```
10 chickens - 6 with A = 1 and 4 with A = 0
1000 penguins - 100 with A = 1 and 900 with A = 0
```

Given A, then probability that it's a chicken is 6/106.

The same logic holds for the more complex case in the question.

EDIT In the case of equal numbers of chickens and penguins (see the comment, below) it is possible to solve the entire thing analytically. Let's start simply, with my same probabilities for 1 condition: 500 chickens, 60% with A = 300 chickens with A.  500 penguins, 10% with A = 50 penguins and the chance of being a chicken given A = 300/350.

The principal is still the same for you complex case; since A, B and C are independent. We just have to figure out the number of chickens given A, B, ~C. This is 500*.60*.10*.20 = 6 chickens. Similarly the number of penguins = 500*.55*.20*.10 = 5.5 penguins and the chance of being a chicken is 6/11.5. In this particular case, we could simplify by noting that the terms for B and C multiply to the same thing for chickens and penguins, and just compare .6 to .55.

Comment: Your point about the number of penguins and chickens is interesting.  And I get what you're saying.  However, the way that I read the question, the answer wasn't intended to be so strongly dependent on the number of chickens or penguins.  What would your answer be if the number of chickens was equal to the number of penguins, and that number was large?

Comment: @rbatt Peter is correct in this well-explained answer. Your comment introduces an assumption not made in the question.

Comment: @whuber & @ Peter: Say quality A is something simple, "the bird is white".  So if a bird is classified as "white", then A = 1 for that individual.  Not all chickens are white, nor are all penguins.  In fact, 60% of chickens are white, as are 55% of penguins. If I find a white bird, what is it?  I think there's a fundamental difference in the way I've interpreted the question, vs. how Peter has.  After re-reading the question and Peter's response more carefully, I think Peter is right, given the question's wording.  Specifically, "**If a chicken**...A holds for **the animal** 60% of the time."

Comment: Given that the bird is white and given that there are equal numbers of chickens and penguins, the probability that the bird is a chicken is 6/11.5.  Without assuming something abou the number of birds, the question cannot be answered. This is a classic problem. It comes up all over the place, e.g. when given the results of a medical test. The fact that the test is positive and that (say) 99% of people with the disease test positive is not enough to say how likely it is that the person who tests positive has the disease. Is the disease rare or common?

Comment: I'm tempted to resort to explaining how one should misread the question to arrive at the same (incorrect) approach that I took, but that's obviously counterproductive! ha.  Good answer, thanks for taking the time to explain.